# Is there a way to run tests on my Webpack packaged code?

Tags: webpack, mocha.js

The use of `require('image.png')` in my unbuilt source code is causing problems with my mocha tests (invalid character).

Is there a way to: package my Webpack project and then run my tests against that pacakged code? I would be able to do this if I could set multiple output directories in Webpack but I see no documentation on how to do that.

**Webpack Config**

```
module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: {
    index: './src/js/index.js'
  },
   // It would be great if this were an Array
  output: {
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    assetModuleFilename: 'assets/test/[name][ext]',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
    clean: true
  },
```

Comment: What tests are you trying to run? End to end or unit tests?

Answer (score 1):

You have to think this problem from different perspective. There are three types of tests that we typically run:

1. Unit tests (on source code while mocking imported/required modules)
2. End to end tests (on deployed code using external runner like Selenium, Cypress, etc.)
3. Integration tests (typically run on source code with less mocking or on deployed code in complex scenarios)

So, trying to run tests for generated code doesn't make sense. Either you run tests for source code or take the compiled code, deploy it and run your tests.

Now, assuming that you are executing unit tests for module `xyz.js` and requiring `require('image.png')` means your module `xyz.js` depends on external module named `image.png`. In this situation, before running tests for `xyz.js`, you should first mock this module `image.png` using some mocking library like `sinon.js`, etc. You need to additionally use [mock-require](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mock-require) or [proxyrequire](https://www.npmjs.com/package/proxyquire) to stub/mock calls to `require` function.

```
const mock = require('mock-require');
const sinon = require('sinon');


describe('My Suite', () => {
  
  before(() => {
    // You can use spy or stub or mock.
    const spy = sinon.spy();
    
    // Mocking you module here 
    mock('image.png', spy);
  });

  it('should call image.png', () => {
    // Add your test here
  });

  after(() => {
    // Mock cleanup
    mock.stop('image.png');
  });
});
```

If you really intend to run the tests for compiled code, then **right way** is to deploy this code to some temporary staging area and use headless browser to access the app and perform required testing.